# Linux Bourne shell substitution issue

Tags: echo, substitution, sh

I'm trying to use substitution in a BS with built data namespace within a (very) small embedded busybox (no man, 60 cmds all in all), but I can't echo the data as soon as there are more than 2 data echoed :

**this is OK** :

```
a=$(echo -e ${smtp_0} ${smtp_4})  
echo $a  
# returns: "0 4" as expected, also all individually printed datas are echoed as expected
```

**this does not echo expected datas** whatever data is:

```
b=$(echo -e ${smtp_0} ${smtp_4} ${smtp_5})
echo $b
# returns: "54" , same with double-quotes (Nok, it should return "0 4 5")
```

Datas are built like this :

"data file sample"

```
val0=1  
val1=1  
...
```

Reading datas shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
x=0  
while read line  
do  
   # fetch values, removing blank and commented lines, eg keeping only lines starting with data namespace
   formatted_line=$(echo $line | sed -e "/^[^a-z].*$/d" | cut -d= -f2)

   # store file's value into a data array-like
   if [ ! -z $formatted_line ];then
      eval "`echo $x | sed -e 's/.*/smtp_&=$formatted_line/'`"
      x=$(($x+1))
   fi
done < $DATA_FILE  

# Then try echoing datas...  
# ... see above ...
```

EDITED:
So it does look like there is nthg mistaken in there but the data file EOL misleading the concatenation of the builtin data. I close the point and thx to Dennis helping getting this headhache fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve whitespace, variables should be quoted:

```
b=$(echo -e "${smtp_0} ${smtp_4} ${smtp_5}")
echo "$b"
```

However, why are you using `echo`?

```
b="${smtp_0} ${smtp_4} ${smtp_5}"
echo "$b"
```

Also, you should use indenting in your code (or if you are then you should retain it when posting questions).

Comment: I also tried with double quotes, same problem. edited: yes this gives the same output w/o "echo". I also tried in command line, there it works if I do : a=0; b=1; c=2; d=$(echo ${a} ${b} ${c}); echo $d. So I guess the problem is sourced in the built data namespaces.

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294864/bourne-shell-how-to-concatenate-variables-that-need-to-be-evaluated), it looks like the point is a concatenation problem which I could not solve yet.

Comment: @hornetbzz: You might find [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) helpful. It has some information on using indirection in non-Bash shells such as Bourne.

Comment: @hornetbzz: I've tested your code in Busybox Ash and it seems to work. I would suggest adding some `echo` statements and use `set -x` to turn on tracing and `set +x` to turn it off around sections of code and do some debugging. You might also want to take a close look at your data file.

Comment: @Dennis: thx, yes I guess the data file is actually the point as I also suspected: adding a _tmp=`echo $tmp | sed -e "s/[^a-z]//g"`_ helped the concat to happen properly. Which I should have seen from the printed results (reverted and only first and last Vs. data file). Thx again for your help.